# How to change linear layout width/height programmatically

Tags: java, android

They always tell me this error "An instance of type
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams'
can not be assigned to a variable of type
'android.widget.AbsList View.LayoutParams'
"

Here is my code:

```
View linear = (View)findViewById(R.id.linear);
                LayoutParams params=linear.getLayoutParams();
                params.width=1;
                linear.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I assume that it means exactly what the error text says. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reassign your LayoutParams to your LinearLayout because in java you are referencing an object. That object is already assigned to `linear` variable. So try to comment yout last line

Answer (score 0):

Can't You try it like this,

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.numberPadLayout);
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 100;//in dp
params.width = 100;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```